# Can someone tell me how my RXJS code work?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
 this.httpService.get('/user/appUser').pipe(
  concatMap(users => users),
  concatMap(user =>
    forkJoin({
      billingAddr: this.httpService
        .get('/user/appUserAddr', new HttpParams()
          .set('where', JSON.stringify([{ pk_addr_name: user['fk_billing_addr_name'] }]))
        ),
      shippingAddr: this.httpService
        .get('/user/appUserAddr', new HttpParams()
          .set('where', JSON.stringify([{ pk_addr_name: user['fk_shipping_addr_name'] }]))
        )
    }).pipe(map(addr => {
      user['billingAddr'] = addr.billingAddr;
      user['shippingAddr'] = addr.shippingAddr;
      return user;
    }))
  ),
  tap(res => console.log(res)),
  toArray()
);
```

The first HTTP Request(get '/user/appUser') whill return an array like this:

```
[  
{user_name:'test1',fk_billing_addr_name:'addr1-1',fk_shipping_addr_name:'addr1-2'},  
{user_name:'test2',fk_billing_addr_name:'addr2-1',fk_shipping_addr_name:'addr2-2'}
]
```

Then I will get the seperate billingAddr and shippingAddr and add it back to the user object itself, which is the second concatMap part.

The final output will look like this:

```
[  
{user_name:'test1',fk_billing_addr_name:'addr1-1',fk_shipping_addr_name:'addr1-2',billingAddr:[...],shippingAddr:[...]},  
{user_name:'test2',fk_billing_addr_name:'addr2-1',fk_shipping_addr_name:'addr2-2',billingAddr:[...],shippingAddr:[...]}
]
```

Actually my code is working, but the weired part is the first concatMap(users=>users).
If I don't put it there, the user array can't emit to the next operator one by one.
Can I simplify it with just one concatMap?
And any other part I can simplify?

Comment: you can use `mergeAll()` or `concatAll()` instead of `concatMap(users => users)`. it is done because originaly event is an array, and with this step you flattern an array to pass only one user to next operators. in the end stream of users is combined back to array with the help of `toArray()` operator

Comment: the thing that concerns me is that 2 requests is made for every user, BUT - untill the requests aren't complete for the first user, requests for the 2nd user do not start. is that ok for your application?

Comment: If I change it to mergeMap, will the final array's order change if the second second user's request finish faster than the fast?

Comment: that is true. order can vary then. if you want to persist order and still make parallel requests, then I believe Michael's answer is the most clear way of resolving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly an interesting question. Here whats happening

1. Get initial array.
2. First `concatMap` emits each element of the array sequentially. Akin to `from(array)`.
3. Map to observable from `forkJoin` using second `concatMap`.
4. Adjust each element by fetching and assigning two new properties to it using `forkJoin`.
5. Combine all the elements/emissions at the end again as an array using `toArray()` operator and emit.

I don't see anything wrong with it except you're waiting the current user to fetch it's data before starting the next.

However if you wish to completely parallelize the fetches, you could use two `forkJoin`s. Inner `forkJoin` is similar to existing usage and outer `forkJoin` to replace the `concatMap` and `toArray`. Here the `switchMap` could be replaced with any other mapping operator. Since Angular HTTP request completes after the first emission, the type of mapping operator used doesn't have any impact.

Note: This is untested code. Please report back any unintended consequences.

```js
this.httpService.get('/user/appUser').pipe(
  switchMap(users => 
    forkJoin(users.map(user => 
      forkJoin({
        billingAddr: this.httpService
          .get('/user/appUserAddr', new HttpParams()
            .set('where', JSON.stringify([{ pk_addr_name: user['fk_billing_addr_name'] }]))
          ),
        shippingAddr: this.httpService
          .get('/user/appUserAddr', new HttpParams()
            .set('where', JSON.stringify([{ pk_addr_name: user['fk_shipping_addr_name'] }]))
          )
      }).pipe(
        map(addr => ({
          ...user,
          billingAddr: addr.billingAddr,
          shippingAddr: addr.shippingAddr
        }))
      )
    ))
  )
)
```

<sup>A equivalent result could be achieved in your code by replacing the `concatMap`s with `mergeMap`s</sup>

Comment: forkJoin accepts a selector as last param. I believe it would be a bit cleaner with selector instead of pipe(map

Comment: @Andrei: `forkJoin` source [explicitly recommends](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L40) to pipe to map instead of using the `resultSelector`.

Comment: @MichaelD: Your example really inspire me for some coding style, and you provide me another way to design me coding. But I prefer Andrei's concatAll() way. Its more flatten and meaningful.

Comment: And one more question is , is there anyway to break the array one by one and do my inner request in just one concatMap?

Comment: @CarlTin: I don't think there is one. Attempting to step through the arrays elements one-by-one will lead to your solution (with two mapping operators). Which I'd say isn't wrong by any means.